# Java. События кнопки

Tags: java, swing, события, button

Учу события кнопки и не могу решить задачу, т.к не понимаю с областями видимости и со смыслом.

**Задание:**

1. Создайте пустое окно.
2. При клике мышью в произвольной точке окна в этом месте должна появиться кнопка.
3. Если кнопок будет уже 10 штук, то должно выводиться сообщение через `JOptionPane`: «Максимум 10 кнопок!»

**Решение:**

```
package guimousehomework;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GUIMouseHomeWork {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Моя программа");
        frame.setBounds(600, 400, 850, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
        JButton button = new JButton("Кнопка");
        top.add(button);   
        frame.add(top);
        frame.setVisible(true);        
        
        
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            int count = 0; 
            
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {   
                count++;
                button.setBounds(me.getX(), me.getY(), 30, 40);
                if(count > 10) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Максимум 10 кнопок!");
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
                 
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
               
            }
        });
                   
    }
    
}
```

Comment: для того чтобы понимать как писать обработчики событий нужно иметь представление о потоке распределения событий.

Comment: На данном этапе потоки еще не рассматриваются.

Comment: А на каком этапе рассматривается динамическое создание компонентов?

Comment: Многопоточное программирование идет последней темой в пособии. Задание дается по теме пользовательских интерфейсов.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы появилась кнопка нужно ее создавать и добавлять на панель

```
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    count++;
    if (count > 10) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Максимум 10 кнопок!"); 
    } else {
      JButton button = new JButton("Кнопка "+count);
      top.add(button);
      button.setBounds(me.getX(), me.getY(), 100, 50);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало.

Comment: если кнопок 10 штук, 11я появляться не должна (хоть это явно и не присутствует в условии), поэтому перенесите условие проверки до создания кнопки.